# How to Get cumulative totals mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I keep information about financial returns. The columns includes receipts,  repairs, service_amount, tyres, fuel, salaries_allowances, others.

I would like to get the cumulative net return like:

```
Date        Receipts       repairs      service amount  Total costs  net Return
2012-01-10  0.00           120,000.00   0.00            120,000.00   120,000.00
2012-01-12  60,000.00      0.00         0.00            60,000.00    60,000.00
```

I am currently using this query:

```
SELECT 
        a.consignment_date, a.receipts, a.service_amount, a.repairs, a.tyres, 
        a.salaries_allowances, a.clearing_fee, a.others, 
        a.service_amount + a.repairs + a.tyres + a.salaries_allowances + a.clearing_fee + a.others as total_costs,
        (b.receipts -(a.service_amount + a.repairs + a.tyres + a.salaries_allowances + a.clearing_fee + a.others)) as netreturn 
FROM 
      vw_local_freight a CROSS JOIN vw_local_freight b 
WHERE 
      a.consignment_date >= b.consignment_date AND a.vehicle_no='123X' 
GROUP BY a.consignment_date
```

Comment: Your question is vague, it doesn't detail how they are calculated, would assume that all costs are counted as "repairs" and are a cost, while receipts are a credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at a query like

```
SELECT 
    consignment_date.*,
    consignment_date.credits - consignment_date.costs AS totalCosts,
    (@runningTotal := @runningTotal + consignment_date.credits - consignment_date.costs) AS netReturn
FROM (
    SELECT
        consignment_date,
        SUM(receipts) AS credits
        SUM(service_amount + repairs + tyres + salaries_allowances + clearing_fee + others) AS costs
    FROM vw_local_freight 
    WHERE vehicle_no = '123x'
    GROUP BY consignment_date
) AS a, (SELECT @runningTotal := 0) AS b
```

The subquery tallies up your costs and credits, then the outer query performs your running total.  If you need individual column sums within the inner join then they can be added in easily enough.

Comment: the above query works fine but i had to make a few changes for me to get the desired result below is the modified query from the one you posted.Thanks Simon ,Ali Issa and Mosty Mostacho you guys gave me an insight

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SELECT
   q1.d,
   q1.c,
   (@runtot := @runtot + q1.c) AS rt
FROM
   (SELECT
       DAYOFYEAR(date) AS d,
       COUNT(*) AS c
    FROM  orders
    WHERE  hasPaid > 0
    GROUP  BY d
    ORDER  BY d) AS q1
```

Comment: where is the point in adding the counts together? i think the OP wants to add sums together and calculate a total

Comment: @Ali Issa the total costs are computed by adding up(sum of) service_amount , repairs ,tyres ,salaries_allowances , clearing_fee  and others while net return is computed by  receipts - sum of total costs but net pay is cumulative.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm basing my answer on your query, rather than on your expected table result:

```
SELECT *, receipts - total_costs as NetReturn FROM (
  SELECT a.consignment_date, sum(a.receipts) receipts, sum(a.service_amount),
    sum(a.repairs), sum(a.tyres), sum(a.salaries_allowances),
    sum(a.clearing_fee), sum(a.others), sum(a.service_amount + a.repairs
    + a.tyres + a.salaries_allowances + a.clearing_fee + a.others) as total_costs
  FROM  vw_local_freight a
  WHERE a.vehicle_no = '123X' 
  GROUP BY a.consignment_date
) S
```